# Usar una animación mientras otro proceso carga

Tags: python, animación, async-await, asyncio

Estoy usando `async` y `await` para que, mientras en la consola aparece una animación, la función `proceso()` cargue, porque la función `proceso()` es una función que toma mucho tiempo ¿Cómo lo hago? Esto es a lo máximo que he llegado

```py
import asyncio
async def proceso():
    # Gran proceso aquí

async def animacion():
    while await proceso(): # ← Esto es lo que quiero hacer, pero no sé como
        # Animación aquí

asyncio.run(animacion())
```

Mientras la función `proceso()` se esté ejecutando, el `while` de la función animación se ejecutará ¿Cómo lo hago?

Comment: A lo mejor los [Hilos](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) te pueden servir.

Answer (score 2):

### Un poco de teoría

La programación asíncrona usa multitarea **colaborativa**, es decir, cada una de las funciones asíncronas que escribas, deben contener alguna instrucción que *ceda el turno* a otra de las funciones.

El bucle de eventos de asyncio se ejecuta en un solo hilo, y no puede interrumpir a una corutina que esté en ejecución. Es la corutina la que debe retornar el control al bucle de eventos en ciertos puntos de su interior. Si la corutina tiene alguna operación de entrada/salida (por ejemplo, lectura de un fichero, operaciones de red, etc) y esas operaciones las hace a través de funciones de la biblioteca `asyncio`, entonces será en esas operaciones en las que cederá el control al bucle de eventos, puesto que en el momento que llame a una de esas operaciones de E/S, por ejemplo `datos = await fichero.read()`, la función `.read()` iniciará la operación de lectura pero no esperará a que se complete, sino que devolverá el control al bucle de eventos, el cual marcará a esa corutina como "pausada" (esperando por entrada/salida) y pasará a ejecutar otra (por ejemplo la que ejecuta la animación).

Cada vez que una corutina se "pausa" en una operación de E/S, el bucle de eventos vuelve a entrar, comprueba si había operaciones de E/S pendientes que hayan terminado ya y si es así pasará a ejecutar a la corutina que estaba esperando por esa operación.

Si las corutinas que lanzas no tienen operaciones de E/S u otros mecanismos para devolver el control al bucle de eventos, entonces **acapararán en hilo**, es decir, seguirán ejecutándose hasta su final. El resto de corutinas que hubieras lanzado no podrán ejecutarse, pues el bucle de eventos no retoma el control para poder continuarlas.

Por eso esta multitarea se llama *colaborativa*, porque las corutinas deben colaborar cediéndose el turno para que otras puedan avanzar. Esto es muy diferente a lo que ocurre cuando haces programación multihilo. En este otro caso no es necesario que los hilos cedan el control, ya que es el propio sistema operativo el que tiene un mecanismo para medir cuánto tiempo lleva ejecutándose un hilo e *interrumpirlo* (esté donde esté en ese momento) en cuanto excede su tiempo permitido, para pasar a ejecutar otro hilo (y volverá al que ha detenido más tarde, todo de forma automática).

La programación multihilo es más sencilla conceptualmente porque no tienes que preocuparte de manejar la concurrencia, el operativo lo hace por tí. Pero en la práctica es muy complejo porque no sabes en qué momento un hilo va a ser interrumpido por el operativo y se le va a ceder el control a otro hilo. Eso hace muy difícil razonar sobre el orden en que se van a ejecutar las cosas, y hace muy difícil también el acceso a variables globales ya que un hilo podría estar cambiando esa variable y *a mitad de la operación* ser interrumpido, dejando la variable en un estado incorrecto (y otro hilo podría leerla en ese estado).

### Respondiendo a tu pregunta

Una forma muy sencilla de ceder el turno en la programación asíncrona es llamar a `asyncio.sleep(T)`. Esta función pausa a la corutina que la contenga, mete en el bucle de eventos la petición de que la reanude de nuevo dentro de T segundos, y cede el control al bucle de eventos (el cual pasará entonces a ejecutar otra corutina que esté lista). Puedes incluso poner T=0, lo cual puede parecer absurdo pero no lo es, ya que sirve para ceder el control para que otra corutina pueda ejecutarse, pero volverá inmediatamente a ésta si no hay otra corutina lista.

Así pues tu código podría ser tal que así:

```py
import asyncio

animacion_sigue = True

async def proceso():
    global animacion_sigue

    # Gran proceso aquí
    # Implementado con algún tipo de bucle
    while True:
       # Hacer una pequeña parte del proceso
       ...
       if proceso_completado:
          animacion_sigue = False
          break
       await asyncio.sleep(0)        # Ceder el turno a otra corutina


async def animacion():
    while animacion_sigue:
       # imprimir un frame de la animación
       ...
       await asyncio.sleep(0.5)      # Ceder turno, y volver aqui dentro de medio segundo

async def main():
    # Lanzar las dos corutinas anteriores a la vez
    # y esperar a que ambas terminen
    await asyncio.gather(proceso(), animacion())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Si la función `proceso()` contiene operaciones de E/S, en ellas también se pausará, dando oportunidad a entrar a la animación si le toca. Para que la animación no acapare mucha CPU, se ejecuta solo un frame y luego "se retira" durante medio segundo. Puedes cambiar ese tiempo como gustes.

Comment: Estoy probando esta respuesta y no me funciona (python 3.10), creo que le hace falta usar `await ...` en cada `...sleep()`.

Comment: Tienes razón. He editado la respuesta para corregirlo.

Answer (score 0):

```
import asyncio

async def proceso():
    task = asyncio.create_task(animacion())
    # Gran proceso aquí

async def animacion():
    while True:
        pass
        # Animación aquí

asyncio.run(proceso())
```

Cuando se inicia la funcion `proceso` se llama a animacion como una tarea asincrona, por lo que animacion se va a ejecutar en un bucle while infinito hasta que la funcion  proceso termine

Comment: Si esas tareas asíncronas no se ceden el turno, solo se ejecutará una y no permitirá que entre la otra.

Comment: Acabo de leer tu respuesta (muy buena por cierto) y ya veo por que dices que no le cedera el paso, aunque me parece que si funcionaria, pues solo estoy ejecutando la corutina "proceso". Dentro de esta corutina lo que hago es llamar a la corutina "animacion()" pero la llamo como una "task" y según la documentación al momento de crearla se ejecuta concurrentemente. Al momento de que proceso finalice, las tasks que tenia dentro se cancelan, por lo que la animación solo estará presente mientras la "proceso()" se ejecuta. Por esta razón no utilice "asyncio.gather()"

Comment: Efectivamente no necesitas gather al lanzarla como task, pero sigue siendo cierto que, aunque tengas dos tareas lanzadas, en realidad solo se ejecuta una (en el caso de tu código, se ejecutará proceso(), mientras animacion() simplemente estará lista esperando su turno. Concurrencia no significa paralelismo. A animacion() le llegará el turno cuando proceso() termine, o cuando le ceda el turno con un sleep() o una operación de E/S.

Comment: Tienes razón, ya lo probé y efectivamente no cede el paso sin un sleep(0). Gracias por tomarte el tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Alternativa utilizando `threading`:

```py
import threading
import time

def thread_process(id):
    print(f"Thread_Process {id}: comenzando")
    time.sleep(10)
    print(f"Thread {id}: terminando")

def thread_animation(id):
    clock=0
    while True:
        clock+=1
        time.sleep(1)
        print(f"thread_animation {id}: {clock}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Main    : Antes de crear el thread de procesos")
    x = threading.Thread(target=thread_process, args=(1,))
    y = threading.Thread(target=thread_animation, args=(2,),daemon=True)
    print("Main    : Antes de lanzar el thread de procesos")
    x.start()
    y.start()
    print("Main    : Esperar a que hilo termine")
    x.join()
    print("Main    : Los procesos han terminado")
```

Código adaptado de: [Intro to python threading](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/)

la función `thread_process` tiene un `time.sleep(10)` que simula la duración del proceso demorado, mientras un hilo está ejecutando esas tareas hay otro hilo ejecutando la animación `thread_animation` para que finalice el `while true` al finalizar el programa se activa el parámetro `daemon`.

Para comprobar el esperar a que se termine de ejecutar `thread_process` usamos `x.join()`

La salida de consola es:

```py
Main    : Antes de crear el thread de procesos
Main    : Antes de lanzar el thread de procesos
Thread_Process 1: comenzando
Main    : Esperar a que hilo termine
thread_animation 2: 1
thread_animation 2: 2
thread_animation 2: 3
thread_animation 2: 4
thread_animation 2: 5
thread_animation 2: 6
thread_animation 2: 7
thread_animation 2: 8
thread_animation 2: 9
Thread 1: terminando
Main    : Los procesos han terminado
```

Comment: [Sólo puedes usar código multi-hilo si eres así de alto](https://bholley.net/blog/2015/must-be-this-tall-to-write-multi-threaded-code.html)